# Getting an error when running react native app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

I am encountering an issue when try to run my app on my local machine. When I run react-native run-android I am confronted with this error and I am not sure what I can do. I have made sure that I have full access rights to all files etc but nothing seems to work. This error stops me from loading my app onto my AVD:

[image: AVD console error]

Please help me!

Comment: Did you try to remove your /node_modules and `$ npm i` again ?

Comment: cd to your android folder in from your app root and exec command `./gradlew clean` to clean. then try run again. In most of my cases, cleaning using gradle fixes the things.

Comment: Yeah that is one of the first things i did, deleted the whole directory and ran npm install

Comment: @AhsanAhmed is that in cmd?

Comment: @hawks yeah run it in cmd inside your android folder

Comment: @AhsanAhmed Thank you so much! i cant believe it was honestly just that i was trying all sorts of things!

Comment: Glad to help @hawks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the Android setup instructions from React Native? Have you tried to delete the directory in the error message? Try those first and try again

Comment: Yeah I followed it word for word, it is frustrating me that i don't have a clue what i am doing wrong

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Put it as comment.